# Extjs Resizable Handle Colour change?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, extjs, extjs4

I've been trying to replace to current CSS class of the resizeable handles in Extjs, specifically the ones for the popup windows. I am trying to change the colour of it and it doesnt seem to be working. Here is my css code

```
.linkWindow .x-toolbar-footer, 
.x-resizable-handle, .x-resizable-handle-west, .x-resizable-handle-east, .x-resizable- handle-south, .x-resizable-handle-over .x-resizable-handle-east, .x-resizable-handle-over .x-resizable-handle-west, .x-resizable-proxy, .x-resizable-overlay

{

    color: #045BB3;
    background-color: #045BB3;
    background: #045BB3;
    border-color: #045BB3;


}
```

I am not sure what to do anymore. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Also it should be noted I am developing for IE 7

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing Extjs css is overwriting your own. try to add `!important` at the end of your properties like this:

```
.linkWindow .x-toolbar-footer, 
.x-resizable-handle, .x-resizable-handle-west, .x-resizable-handle-east, .x-resizable- handle-south, .x-resizable-handle-over .x-resizable-handle-east, .x-resizable-handle-over .x-resizable-handle-west, .x-resizable-proxy, .x-resizable-overlay

{

    color: #045BB3 !important;
    background: #045BB3 !important;
    border-color: #045BB3 !important;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The handles are actually gif images. You'd need to edit the gifs for each piece of the splitter bar. For instance extjs4/resources/themes/images/default/sizer/s-handle.gif is one.